# QGraphicsItem's - selection & rotation

Tags: qt, rotation, qgraphicsitem

I'd like to implement application which allows user to select few `QGraphicsItems` and then rotate them as a group. I know that I could add all items into one `QGraphicsItemGroup` but I need to keep `Z-value` of each item. Is it possible?

I also have a second question. 
I'm trying to rotate `QGraphicsItem` around some point (different from `(0,0)` - let's say `(200,150)`). After that operation I want to rotate this item once more time but now around `(0,0)`. I'm using code below:

```
    QPointF point(200,150); // point is (200,150) at first time and then it is changed to (0,0) - no matter how...
    qreal x = temp.rx();
    qreal y = temp.ry();
    item->setTransform(item->transform()*(QTransform().translate(x,y).rotate(angle).translate(-x,-y)));
```

I noticed that after second rotation the item is not rotated around point `(0,0)` but around some other point (I don't know which). I also noticed that if I change order of operations it all works great.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first problem, why should the z-values be a problem when putting them into a QGraphicsGroup?
On the other hand you could also iterate through the selected items and just apply the transformation.

I guess this snippet will solve your 2nd problem:

```
QGraphicsView view;
QGraphicsScene scene;

QPointF itemPosToRotate(-35,-35);
QPointF pivotPoint(25,25);

QGraphicsEllipseItem *pivotCircle = scene.addEllipse(-2.5,-2.5,5,5);              
pivotCircle->setPos(pivotPoint);

QGraphicsRectItem *rect = scene.addRect(-5,-5,10,10);
rect->setPos(itemPosToRotate);

// draw some coordinate frame lines
scene.addLine(-100,0,100,0);
scene.addLine(0,100,0,-100);

// do half-cicle rotation
for(int j=0;j<=5;j++)
for(int i=1;i<=20;i++) {
    rect = scene.addRect(-5,-5,10,10);
    rect->setPos(itemPosToRotate);

    QPointF itemCenter = rect->pos();
    QPointF pivot = pivotCircle->pos() - itemCenter;


    // your local rotation
    rect->setRotation(45);

    // your rotation around the pivot
    rect->setTransform(QTransform().translate(pivot.x(), pivot.y()).rotate(180.0 * (qreal)i/20.0).translate(-pivot.x(),-pivot.y()),true);
}
view.setScene(&scene);
view.setTransform(view.transform().scale(2,2));
view.show();
```

EDIT:
In case you meant to rotate around the global coordinate frame origin change the rotations to:

```
rect->setTransform(QTransform().translate(-itemCenter.x(), -itemCenter.y()).rotate(360.0 * (qreal)j/5.0).translate(itemCenter.x(),itemCenter.y()) );
rect->setTransform(QTransform().translate(pivot.x(), pivot.y()).rotate(180.0 * (qreal)i/20.0).translate(-pivot.x(),-pivot.y()),true);
```

Comment: let's say I have few items on my scene (name=Z-value):
(item1=1, item2=2, item3=3, item4=4)
Now I want to group two of them:
[Group(item1=1,item3=3)]=5
This operation will make item1 and item3 will go to the top of my scene. I want to have "stack of layers" of my scene unchanged no matter if items are grouped or not.

Comment: i dont understand what you actually want to do...
either draw a picture or rephrase your problem precisely.
The code i posted does the rotations you wanted (your 2nd question), unless by "once more time but now around (0,0)" you mean about the origin of the global coordinate frame.
In this case just do another rotation similar to the pivot rotation but change the pivot to (0,0).
I still dont know what you mean with "stack of layers unchanged...".

Do you want to rotate multiple objects around a pivot and preserve their local rotation maybe?